# How to set a properties file with some custom configuration

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a code to read the values from an excel file using Apache POI, the content of this excel file is a big table with multiple columns and many rows and there is many excel files with the same structure (number of columns), and some times may have different column name and different column values.

One of my requirements is to ingest all the data in two different data types, one is the numerical data which is a Float type, and the other is the text value as a String.

Question 1: How to pass this logic into a properties file, so this way every time I need to parse an excel file it can take the external file with the correct set of data type for each column?

Question 2: In my approach bellow I set the column position as a key to identify the position, but I think it's much better instead of having a numerical value, have the column name as a key, in this case is faster to read the properties file and set the data type value depending on the name of column.

Currently I came with the logic bellow to fix the column position with it's data type either String or Float, and its fine for one particular excel file.

```
     String filePath;
     String fileProcessingType;

     Map<Integer, List<MergeCellRange>> mergeCellMap = new HashMap<>();
     Map<Integer, String> columnHeaderMap = new HashMap<>(););

     static NavigableMap<Integer, String> columnTypeMap = null; // map is used to identify the column
     // types of each parameter
    static {
      columnTypeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
      columnTypeMap.put(0, "String");
      columnTypeMap.put(1, "String"); // 1 TimeStamp as String
      columnTypeMap.put(2, "String"); // 2-66 String
      columnTypeMap.put(66, "String"); // 66 String
      columnTypeMap.put(67, "Float"); // 67-88 String
      columnTypeMap.put(89, "String"); // 89-90 String
      columnTypeMap.put(113, "String"); // 114....
    }
```

So my idea is to have a properties file like:

```
 Column0=String
 Column1=String
 Column2=Float
 Column3=String
 Column4=Float
 Column5=Float
 Column6=String
 ...
```

And then pick it out calling the properties file:

FileInputStream newFile = new FileInputStream("dataType.properties");

```
Properties mappingFile = new Properties();
mappingFile.load(newFile);

mappingFile.load(newFile);

List = mappingFile.getProperties().list(System.out);

static NavigableMap<List> columnTypeMap = null; 
// map is used to identify the column
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
try(FileInputStream newFile=new FileInputStream("dataType.properties")) {
  Properties mappingFile =new Properties();
  mappingFile.load(newFile);
  mappingFile.forEach((c,t)-> {
    columnTypeMap.put(Integer.parseInt(((String)c).substring("Column".length())),(String)t);
  });
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  System.error.println(ex);
}
```

PS: You could just write your properties as

```
00=String
01=Float
02=...
```

and reduce the mapping part to

```java
    columnTypeMap.put(Integer.parseInt((String)c),(String)t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
[Apache PropertiesConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html).
It still solves the basics for you: open and parse the properties file and provide its content by key. Examples can be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may check [POI's documentation on getting the data type of a cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--).

If that doesn't work for you, I recommend you taking a look at [Java Properties class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). You can get a list of all available properties in the file [by key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#keySet()) or [by (key,value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#entrySet()). After knowing the data type expected, processing the cell is straightforward: [as string](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue--), [as a double](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue--).